# SharePoint and metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata

Is there a way to upload files to SharePoint and maintain the original metadata (creator, date created, etc.)?

We attempted uploading using Edge and looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of migration tools they will allow you to create mappings and keep the data together.

Answer (score -1):

No. SharePoint has it's own defautl metadata which would override the original metadata (creator, date created).

As a workaround, you could create some custom fields in the library where you upload files to. Then use these custom fields to store the original metadata.